# Working in git branch. Can I rebase to keep branch updates?

Tags: git, git-svn

My firm is using Subversion but I am turned on with git right now so I am doing the following:

```
git svn clone -s http://svn/java/<project> <project>
cd <project>
git svn show-ignore > .gitignore
git checkout -b dev
```

Now if I am working in my dev branch overnight and I want to see if anyone changed the trunk of svn can I just issue a

```
git svn rebase
```

in my dev branch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can run `git svn rebase` as much as you want.  It will work fine from git branches.

Since it is likely that the only way that other people would see your code would be through the svn server, you don't even need to be concerned about rewriting history as is usually the case with use of rebase, since the commit IDs don't make it through svn in any case.

Comment: but will my code in my branch be updated if something changed in version

Comment: Yes, `git svn rebase` pulls changes from the latest svn branch which was the origin of the most recent svn commit reachable from the current git branch.